# INSERT statements gives me different errors

Tags: sql, insert, oracle11g

I'm trying to run a file which contains INSERT statements. The statements will either give me an `not enough values` error or `unique constraint` error.

Below is my create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE PART 
    (PNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     PName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
     PUnitPrice NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL,
     ComponentOf VARCHAR(25),
            CONSTRAINT PART_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(PNum),
            CONSTRAINT PART_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(ComponentOf)
            REFERENCES PART(PNum)
    };
CREATE TABLE MANUFACTURER
    (MName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     MAddress VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     MPhone VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT MANUFACTURER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(MName),
    );
CREATE TABLE PART-MANUFACTURED 
    (MDate DATE,not null
     PNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     MName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     Quantity NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT PART-MANUFACTURED_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(MName,PNum,MDate),
            CONSTRAINT PART-MANUFACTURED_FKEY1  FOREIGN KEY(PNum)
                REFERENCES PART(PNum),
            CONSTRAINT PART-MANUFACTURED_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(MName)
                REFERENCES MANUFACTURER(MName)
    );
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
    (CNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     CName VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
     CType VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(CNum),
            CONSTRAINT CHECK_CType 
                CHECK(CType IN (‘INDIVIDUAL,’INSTITUITION’))
    );
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
    (CNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     PNum VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
     OrderDate DATE NOT NULL,
     OrderQuantity NUMBER(7,2) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(CNum,PNum,OrderDate),
            CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY(CNum)
                REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CNum),
            CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(PNum)
                REFERENCES PART(PNum)
    );
```

Below is the statement that gives me the `not enough values` error:

```
INSERT INTO PART
VALUES('S001','System-Economy',1100,null);
INSERT INTO PART
VALUES('M001','Monitor-17 inch',250,'S001');
```

For the `unique constraints` error, I believe i have to insert the data in order of their primary and referencing keys right?

So what do I need to change in order for the the insert statements to work?

Comment: @AlmaDo Oracle XE 11G?

Comment: @TimSchmelter what do you mean?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I believe i just answered that question ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see any error on Insert. The problem is with your create table. Plenty to correct. Try this

```
CREATE TABLE PART ( PNUM VARCHAR ( 25 ) NOT NULL,
                PNAME VARCHAR ( 75 ) NOT NULL,
                PUNITPRICE NUMBER ( 7, 2 ) NOT NULL,
                COMPONENTOF VARCHAR ( 25 ),
                CONSTRAINT PART_PKEY PRIMARY KEY ( PNUM ),
                CONSTRAINT PART_FKEY FOREIGN KEY
                    ( COMPONENTOF )
                     REFERENCES PART ( PNUM ) );

CREATE TABLE MANUFACTURER ( MNAME VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
                       MADDRESS VARCHAR ( 100 ) NOT NULL,
                       MPHONE VARCHAR ( 25 ) NOT NULL,
                       CONSTRAINT MANUFACTURER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY ( MNAME ) );

CREATE TABLE PART_MANUFACTURED ( MDATE DATE NOT NULL,
                           PNUM VARCHAR ( 25 ) NOT NULL,
                           MNAME VARCHAR ( 50 ) NOT NULL,
                           QUANTITY NUMBER ( 10 ) NOT NULL,
                           CONSTRAINT PART_MANUFACTURED_PKEY PRIMARY KEY
                               ( MNAME, PNUM, MDATE ),
                           CONSTRAINT PART_MANUFACTURED_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY
                               ( PNUM )
                                REFERENCES PART ( PNUM ),
                           CONSTRAINT PART_MANUFACTURED_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY
                               ( MNAME )
                                REFERENCES MANUFACTURER ( MNAME ) );

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER ( CNUM VARCHAR ( 25 ) NOT NULL,
                    CNAME VARCHAR ( 75 ) NOT NULL,
                    CTYPE VARCHAR ( 20 ) NOT NULL,
                    CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PKEY PRIMARY KEY ( CNUM ),
                    CONSTRAINT CHECK_CTYPE CHECK
                        ( CTYPE IN ('INDIVIDUAL', 'INSTITUITION') ) );

CREATE TABLE ORDERS ( CNUM VARCHAR ( 25 ) NOT NULL,
                  PNUM VARCHAR ( 25 ) NOT NULL,
                  ORDERDATE DATE NOT NULL,
                  ORDERQUANTITY NUMBER ( 7, 2 ) NOT NULL,
                  CONSTRAINT ORDERS_PKEY PRIMARY KEY
                      ( CNUM, PNUM, ORDERDATE ),
                  CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY1 FOREIGN KEY
                      ( CNUM )
                       REFERENCES CUSTOMER ( CNUM ),
                  CONSTRAINT ORDERS_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY
                      ( PNUM )
                       REFERENCES PART ( PNUM ) );

INSERT INTO
      PART
VALUES
      ( 'S001',
        'System-Economy',
        1100,
        NULL );


INSERT INTO
      PART
VALUES
      ( 'M001',
        'Monitor-17 inch',
        250,
        'S001' );
```

Comment: Use some tools to check the difference... Mainly typos, improper commas, unsupported characters on table name, using {} instead of ()... etc etc

Comment: I still get the same errors as before even after changing to create table u gave me.

Comment: This is so weird, it works fine. see the fiddle here. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/05e890/1/0

Comment: dammm. So is there anything else that i can do?

Comment: Did you see the fiddle? If yes, Nothing much you need to do. Accept this as answer and close the question. For me the issue is with your code snippet.

Comment: Could there be something wrong with my setup of the oracle 11g?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that... the bitter truth is that it behaves like this if you give wrong commands. The problem is in your SQL statements

Comment: It appears I forgot that I had added a couple of new rows to my existing tables in another script. That's why my insert statements wouldn't work because it IS missing a few values. Thanks to realspiriturals for this reminder.